# Cannot run from pychon console in Pycharm but can run scrip

Tags: python, pycharm

It is a wired question. I have a project folder and in this folder, I have a project.py and another src folder for my own module, let's say module.py. I also made this src folder as my root source folder.

The project.py can be run successfully(right-click the tab and select run project.py). However, when I copy the whole script into the python console and run it, it says `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'module'`.

Any thoughts?

Comment: paste the import lines of the code

Comment: import module # my module.py in src folder

Comment: Python can't find the file module.py because the console probably isn't running in the same directory as the file. Try `import os; print(os.getcwd())`

Comment: Do you mean PyCharm built-in Python console or the one outside of the IDE?

Comment: Hi Pavel, I mean Pycharm built-in python console.

Comment: @9 Guy the print out shows the root folder of the project, what then?